# Create event/date graph in R but you don't have event # calculated

Tags: r, statistics, shiny, frequency

How would you find the number of events that share a certain date but not time to then graph the frequency in a line graph?

For instance. my input data is below.  I want to make a graph that has an X axis for DATE and Y axis for frequency.  I am unsure how R would calculate that there are three date1 events, 2 date2 events, and 1 date3 event.  Any support is appreciated!

```
DATE  | TIME | 
date1 |  xa
date1 |  xb
date1 |  xc
date2 |  xd
date2 |  xe
date3 |  xf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dplyr is your answer, do as follows, lets say your data is a data.frame called df:

```
library(dplyr)


by_date <- group_by(df, DATE)

by_date <- summarise(by_date, frecuency = n())
```

then you will be able to graph it, if you need help with the graph let me know

Comment: Appreciate it.  Apparently my version of R did not support the (d)plyr package and I am setting it up.  This looks hopeful though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you provided reproducible data. However, look into `count` function of the `plyr` package.

Assuming your dataframe is called `list`, you can run something like following to get the frequency:

```
library(plyr)
frequency = count(list, vars = "DATE")
```

You can then use `frequency` to create your graph.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(frequency = .N) , by = DATE]
```